# Output Shopify Article by Article ID

Tags: shopify

The loop for Shopify Blog Articles is:

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to output articles by different ID. Let's say 33, 65, 81. I have this custom field where I can write the ID's I want and is outputted by:

```
{% if article.metafields.c_f.recommended_post %}{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the metafield contains a single article ID and is saved in Shopfiy as an integer, you can basically just combine the two pieces of code you already have:

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}
    {% if article.id == article.metafields.c_f.recommended_post %}
        {% comment %} Found recommended article {% endcomment %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If your metafield contains a single article ID but is saved in Shopify as a string you need one extra step to covert the metafield value to an integer:

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}
    {% assign recommended_post = article.metafields.c_f.recommended_post | plus: 0 %}
    {% if article.id == recommended_post %}
        {% comment %} Found recommended article {% endcomment %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If your metafield contains multiple article IDs, separated by commas like "33, 65, 81" you can use the [split filter](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#split) and [contains operator](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/operators#contains), and convert your article id to a string instead:

```
{% assign recommended_ids = article.metafields.c_f.recommended_post | split: ', ' %}
{% for article in blog.articles %}
    {% assign article_id = article.id | append: '' %}
    {% if recommended_ids contains article_id %}
        {% comment %} Found one of many recommended articles {% endcomment %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For more information on saving metafields as either strings or integers see: https://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield